# Git multiple config files

Tags: git

As it is told in git-config manual, I have three files to specify git repo configuration: `$GIT_DIR/config`, `~/.gitconfig` and `$(prefix)/etc/gitconfig`. Is it possible to make git read another config file (for example `.gitconfig` in root of the repo) after reading `$GIT_DIR/config`?

I want it as I created git command aliases in `.git/config` and I would prefer to store them in repo, so I can restore them when cloning and for example.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to check some of my settings in, so I use an include file. In the root of my repo I have a .myGitConfig file and in my .git\config file I have this:

```
[include]
    path = ..\\gitconfig
```

Your syntax may be different if you aren't using Windows. The only trick is that you have to have to add that include line to every .git\config file. That's the best I could come up with. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

`GIT_CONFIG` environment variable and `-f` command line option are the only ways how to specify custom config file and this will read that single file only.

My informed guess on the answer is *You can store the config file in git, but users will have to merge changes to .git/config manually.*

Also note that using file under git's control may lead to issues where different branches have different config files with different remotes and branches - seems like a way to ask for troubles.